# How to capture groups

Tags: c#, regex

In C# and NET regex engine, I have an input line like this and it is terminated by `\n`

```
1ROSS/SVETA/JAMIE MRS T02XT 2WHITE/VIKA MS 3GREEN/ANDYMR
```

I have to obtain

First capture

```
 1. num=1
 2. surname=ROSS
 3. name=SVETA
 4. name=JAMIE 
 5. title=MRS 
 6. other=T02XT
```

Second capture

```
1. num=2
2. surname=WHITE
3. name=VIKA 
4. title=MS
```

Third capture

```
1. num=3
2. surname=GREEN
3. name=ANDY
4. title=MR
```

The first group has two names and there is no space within ANDY and MR in the third group. I am unable to solve this problem. I started using

```
(^\d|\s\d)
```

to detect the groups and it works, but after I do not know how to capture till the end of each group and split into subgroups the inside data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the title values are set to `MR`, `MRS` or `MS`, you may use

```
\b(?<num>\d)(?<surname>\p{L}+)(?:/(?<name>\p{L}+?))+(?:\s*(?<title>M(?:RS?|S)))?\b\s*(?<other>.*?)(?=\b\d\p{L}+/\p{L}|$)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3Cnum%3E%5Cd%29%28%3F%3Csurname%3E%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%29%28%3F%3A%2F%28%3F%3Cname%3E%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%3F%29%29%2B%28%3F%3A%5Cs*%28%3F%3Ctitle%3EM%28%3F%3ARS%3F%7CS%29%29%29%3F%5Cb%5Cs*%28%3F%3Cother%3E.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5Cb%5Cd%5Cp%7BL%7D%2B%2F%5Cp%7BL%7D%7C%24%29&i=1ROSS%2FSVETA%2FJAMIE%20MRS%20T02XT%202WHITE%2FVIKA%20MS%203GREEN%2FANDYMR)

**Details**

- `\b`  - word boundary
- `(?<num>\d)` - Group "num": a digit (replace with `\d+` if there can be more than 1)
- `(?<surname>\p{L}+)` - Group "surname": 1+ letters
- `(?:/(?<name>\p{L}+?))+` - one or more sequences of `/` followed with Group "surname": 1+ letters, as few as possible
- `(?:\s*(?<title>M(?:RS?|S)))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?<title>M(?:RS?|S))` - Group "title": `M` followed with `R` and optional `S` or followed with `S`
- `\b` -  word boundary
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<other>.*?)` - Group "other": 0 or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\b\d\p{L}+/\p{L}|$)` - up to the first occurrence of the initial pattern (word boundary, digit, 1+ letters, `/` and a letter) or end of string.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/vn45h4):

```
var text = "1ROSS/SVETA/JAMIE MRS T02XT 2WHITE/VIKA MS 3GREEN/ANDYMR";
var pattern = @"\b(?<num>\d)(?<surname>\p{L}+)(?:/(?<name>\p{L}+?))+(?:\s*(?<title>M(?:RS?|S)))?\b\s*(?<other>.*?)(?=\b\d\p{L}+/\p{L}|$)";
var result = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
foreach (Match m in result) {
    Console.WriteLine("Num: {0}", m.Groups["num"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Surname: {0}", m.Groups["surname"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Names: {0}", string.Join(", ", m.Groups["name"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value)));
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", m.Groups["title"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Other: {0}", m.Groups["other"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("===== NEXT MATCH ======");
}
```

Output:

```
Num: 1
Surname: ROSS
Names: SVETA, JAMIE
Title: MRS
Other: T02XT 
===== NEXT MATCH ======
Num: 2
Surname: WHITE
Names: VIKA
Title: MS
Other: 
===== NEXT MATCH ======
Num: 3
Surname: GREEN
Names: ANDY
Title: MR
Other: 
===== NEXT MATCH ======
```

Comment: @novice_cplusplus Then replace `(?<title>M(?:RS?|S))` with `(?<title>M(?:RS?|(?:IS)?S))`. I'd suggest `(?<title>MR|MRS|MISS|MS)` but it is in an optional subpattern in the middle of a pattern, and this will be too inefficient, so, I'd rather "enhance" this  part.